# Right way of implementing MediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStreamAsync in Web API

Tags: .net, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api, task-parallel-library

I was implementing my own `MediaTypeFormatter` and I have some questions about the method `WriteToStreamAsync` for a custom XML serializer I am doing:

```
public override Task WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content, TransportContext transportContext)
```

I have seen a lot of examples that operates synchronously, and in order to return a `Task`, they enclose the code in a `Task.Factory.StartNew()`, but... is that OK? I mean, doesn't that beat the point of having a Task linked IO operations to improve scalability?

I have found two possible solutions:

First, I use a `StreamWriter` and return the `FlushAsync` task.

```
    public override Task WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content, TransportContext transportContext)
    {
        XDocument doc = new XDocument();
        doc.Add(SerializeType(type, value));

        var sw = new StreamWriter(writeStream,Encoding.UTF8,4096);
        sw.AutoFlush = false;
        doc.Save(sw);
        return sw.FlushAsync();
    }
```

My question here is, what will happen with the `StreamWriter` afterwards? I guess the framework will dispose the `writeStream`, but what about the `StreamWriter`?

The other, I use a internal memory stream, and `WriteAsync` to the `writeStream`:

```
    public override Task WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content, TransportContext transportContext)
    {
        XDocument doc = new XDocument();
        doc.Add(SerializeType(type, value));

        Byte[] buffer = null;
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(4096))
        {
            doc.Save(ms);
            buffer = ms.ToArray();
        }

        return writeStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    }
```

Which would it be the best way of doing it?

Answer (score 3):

When I have an operation that I know is going to run synchronously, but needs a Task as a return value, I use a TaskCompletionSource instance to create a completed Task and return that.

```
 public override Task WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content, TransportContext transportContext)
    {
        XDocument doc = new XDocument();
        doc.Add(SerializeType(type, value));

        doc.Save(writeStream);

        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
        tcs.SetResult(null);
        return tcs.Task;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`StartNew` is for compute-bound work and not for I/O bound. Obviously, it does not make sense to give a thread because that thread has to just wait as well. MSDN says

> Use the StartNew method only when you require fine-grained control for
>   a long-running, compute-bound task.

You can use `using` something like this.

```
public override async Task WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, object value, 
                                              Stream stream, 
                                              HttpContent content, 
                                              TransportContext transportContext)
{                                     
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(JsonpCallbackFunction))
    {
        await base.WriteToStreamAsync(type, value, stream, content,
                                                            transportContext);
        return;
    }

    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
    {
        writer.Write(JsonpCallbackFunction + "(");
        writer.Flush();

        await base.WriteToStreamAsync(type, value, stream, content,
                                                            transportContext);

        writer.Write(")");
        writer.Flush();
    }
}
```

I quote [Brad Wilson](https://gist.github.com/bradwilson/3411200).

Comment: The MSDN documentation for WriteToStreamAsync states "An implementation of this method should NOT close writeStream upon completion" - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn479105(v=vs.118).aspx. The default constructor for StreamWriter causes the stream to be disposed when the writer is disposed.

Comment: Easy, just do this to leave it open: using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(stream, UTF8, 1460, leaveOpen: true)) {